# Files under Program Files have a split personality

Tags: ruby, windows, installation, nsis

I have a Ruby application I'm installing (along with a packaged ruby interpreter) under Program Files on Windows 7 with an NSIS-built installer.  In order to debug it, I edited one of the files to add some debugging statements. After that, I uninstalled the package and ran a new version of the installer which includes a new copy of the edited file, without debugging statements.

Now, I can't get the new copy to load into ruby.  If I run `type <filename>` in cmd.exe, or open the file in Notepad.exe or Firefox, I see the new version.  If I run `ruby -e "puts File.read('<filename>')"`, or open the file in emacs, I see the old version.

If, in Windows Explorer, I copy the file to a new filename, everything can see the new contents at that filename. If I delete the original file and rename the copy to replace the original, the split personality returns.

This situation survives a reboot, so it's not a simple matter of a file being accidentally held open.

What on earth is going on here?  Is there some aspect of the install process that might be checkpointing the file in a way I can revert, or at least switch off while I'm debugging the installer?

**update**

If I run `ruby -e "puts File.read('<filename>')"` in a console that is run as administrator, I see the correct, new contents. How *should* I be managing this file?

Comment: Are you using complete paths?

Comment: Yes, I am. The only difference across any of the situations as far as the path was concerned was substituting backslashes and forward slashes, but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, do not put files you plan to change a lot in Program Files. From Vista onward, there is an interesting way things work to "allow" you to write to a protected file, but it really gets stored in your app data directories, not actually in Program Files. So, utilities that go through the Windows API find the "new" version of the file correctly, but utilities that are more low-level (ruby.exe) only find the existing version. If you navigate to that folder, do you see a "Compatibility Files" button right above the contents? Press that and you'll see your updated version.

Scott Hanselman wrote a [good article about this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VistasShowCompatibilityFilesAndTheScrumptiousWonderThatIsFileVirtualization.aspx) when it was introduced in Vista.

You can only write to the real file when you're logged on as Administrator.

Comment: I doubt ruby.exe bypasses Windows API when opening files. :)

Comment: Yeah, the only reason I was editing these files at all was because the installer wasn't working properly - I'd got a path wrong somewhere else and needed to inject some debug output.  Ordinarily these files won't be edited.

Answer (score 2):

I think it has to do with UAC file system virtualization. Check whether your file exists in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`. If it does, delete it from the VirtualStore.

The fact you see the correct file when running Administrator console proves that it's because of virtualization: UAC virtualization is turned off for elevated processes.